# selenium webdriverwait does not reset timer in for loop | python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python3.8.5 & selenium3.141.0 to automate login processes. To am locating login buttons with css selectors, but in my testing, the selectors can change (i'm a little fuzzy on this - something dynamic to do with how the page loads??).

My current solution for this is iterate over a list of css selectors that I have observed (they do repeat):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
success = True
errorMSG = ""

for loginClickID in paper.loginClickID:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 12)
        try:
            wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, loginClickID)
            ) 
        except Exception as e:  
            log("\nFailed to see click-to-login element: " + loginClickID + "\nHTML output shown below:\n\n" + driver.page_source)
            success = False
                errorMSG = e

if not success:
        response = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
        return f"{paper.brand} login_fail\nLoginClickID: {loginClickID}\nNot found in:\n{response}\n{errorMSG}\n"
```

I am creating a new `WebDriverWait()` object for each iteration of the loop. However, when I debug the code and step over it manually, the second time I enter the loop the `wait.until()` method exits immediately, without even throwing an exception (which is very strange, right?) and exiting the loop completely (the css selector list has 2 elements)

My thought is that somehow the `wait.until()` timer is not reseting?

I've tried reloading the page using `driver.refresh()`, and sleeping the python code using `time.sleep(1)` in the `except:` section in that hope that might help rest things - it has not...

I've included all my ChromeDriver options for context:

```
options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1400,1500")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("enable-automation")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
```

I am using:
Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106
&
ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why use

> css selectors

Which are obvious dynamic, as you say - they change..

Why don't you use Xpath?

```
xpath_email = "//input[@type='email']"
xpath_password = "//input[@type='password']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_email)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xapth_password)
```

These are obviously, generic xpaths, but you can find them on whatever login page you are, and change accordingly.

This way, no matter whatever the test case, your logic will work.

Comment: my testing is showing that xpath can also be dynamic if the html element does not have an id field...